# Integrate $\int \frac{25 - x^2}{x^4} \operatorname d\!x$

Tags: calculus, integration

I think we use trig substitution for this. But I'm not sure where to even begin with this

$$\int \frac{25 - x^2}{x^4} \operatorname d\!x$$

Comment: Doesn't look like a trigonometric substitution would help. It's plain $$\frac{25}{x^4} - \frac{1}{x^2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Not at all. $$\frac{25 - x^2}{x^4} = 25x^{-4} - x^{-2}$$ and continue...

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \dfrac{25-x^2}{x^4}dx=\int\dfrac{25}{x^4}dx-\int\dfrac{1}{x^2}dx\\
=\boxed{-\dfrac{25}{3x^3}+\dfrac{1}{x}}$$